# How to add missing quote to csv file

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm getting a malformed csv from a customer, that is missing a quote on one of the columns just like this

```
"ID","Name","Org_ID","TransType","Amount"
"1453","John Joe","AZ7629","CREDIT_CARD,"23.44"
```

Observe the missing quote after CREDIT_CARD.  It should read as "CREDIT_CARD".
This missing quote is breaking my processor.
I need to pre-process the csv and add this missing quote on any rows missing it.
Is there a way to script this? 
This processing operates after misnight, and manually updating is a NO-OP.
The producers of the csv will fix the issue on their end, but it isn't on the schedule until June 15th.
Please help.

Comment: Is it always after CREDIT_CARD or is the field different each line? Is it possible to replace `",` (without a second quote) and `,"` (without first quote) with `","`? I am thinking about quotes and commas as valid field value.

Comment: The actual value varies, but it is always an alphabetical string.

Comment: Do you know that the character ',' will never occur inside of quotes?

Comment: If 2 quotes were missing, how would you know? Does `"a","b,c","d"` have 2 missing quotes (one after b and one before c so it should be `a","b","c","d"`) or none? How do you know that?

Comment: @AllanL What Ed Moton means is that for the solutions to work, you need the garanty that no comma can exist within a colunm data.  Without this garanty, there will always exist, for a paticuliar solution, an input that will break it.

Comment: Yes, I finally have the affirmation from the upstream supplied that no comma will be in the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!
longer than the sed counterpart but more readable (in my opinion) and can be instrumented to log which values are updated.

```
$ awk -v RS=[,\n] -v q='"' '!/^"/{b=q} !/"$/{e=q} 
                           {printf "%s", b $0 e RT; b=e=""}' file
```

tokenize and add missing quotes

Comment: Thank you - I'm using this one in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^"]\),/\1",/'
```

Comment: Add the `g` modifier, otherwise it will only fix the first missing quote on the line.

Comment: Thank you, this could work.. I have two potential fixes.  I will try them and report back.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each field must be enclosed, you can fix missing closing quotes with this perl command line that ensures that there is an even number of quotes until the end of the record *(otherwise it will add a quote for each field that ends with a comma)*:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=[^"\n])(?=(?:,"[^"]*")*$)/"/' file
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.